# restricted\write18 enabled, on MacOS, when I try to compile to a PDF on TeXMaker and TeXshop

Tags: shell-escape

How to solve this error message: restricted\write18 enabled, on MacOS, when I try to compile to a PDF on TeXMaker and TeXshop.

Comment: It's not an error, it's information: unless you need unrestricted `\write18`, there's nothing to worry about

Comment: From what I know: Its the setting at Mac OS Sys Preferences>Security & Privacy, privacy tab and add TexShop ... this allows the app to run locally . I hope it helps